# jquery find preceding sibling

Tags: jquery, dom, traversal

I am wanting with jquery to find the preceding sibling of an element, so for a example,

```
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" alt="Profile Image"/>
        <hgroup>
            <h5>Person Number 1</h5>
            <h6>Recruitment Consultant</h6>
        </hgroup>
     </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" alt="Profile Image"/>
        <hgroup>
            <h5>Person Number 2</h5>
            <h6>Recruitment Consultant</h6>
        </hgroup>
     </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" alt="Profile Image"/>
        <hgroup>
            <h5>Person Number 3</h5>
            <h6>Recruitment Consultant</h6>
        </hgroup>
     </a>
</li>
```

If I were to hover of the second list element `a` how would I find the previous `li`'s `a`?

My attempt is below,

```
$('resultsset a').hover(function(){
    $(this).prev().find('li a').css('bottom-bottom', '1px solid #000');
},
function() {
    $(this).prev().find('li a').css('bottom-border', '1px solid #c0c0c0');
});
```

Comment: Try `$(this).parent().prev().find('a').css(...)`

Comment: I think `bottom-bottom` and `bottom-border` are supposed to be `border-bottom`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close.  You want to find the element's parent's previous sibling and then find the `a` within that.

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().prev('li').children('a').first();
```

The `.prev('li')` ensures that the sibling is really a `<li>`.

Using `.children('a')` ensures that only immediate descendants are considered.

Comment: I believe `prev()` in a `ul li` list is going to be `li` else it is invalid html.

Comment: @Vega fair point, but no harm in checking, just in case the supplied HTML wasn't valid :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('resultsset a').hover(function(){
     $(this).parent().prev().find('a').css('bottom-bottom', '1px solid #000');
},
```

Comment: `.prev()` would be the li -> He want to highlight the `a`

Comment: Yah noticed that after... fixed.